# Switch doesn't work in SMSegmentViev

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mobile

I use frames SMSegmentView, I can not implement the switch in numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath ... When you start in the simulator by pressing the segment table is not changed by pressing the index segment. I can not understand the error

```
import UIKit

class DailyStandingViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, SMSegmentViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var standingTableView: UITableView!

let standingExersiseName = ["БЕГ", "ПРЫЖКИ", "ПРИСЕДАНИЯ", "ОТЖИМАНИЯ", "ТОЛЧЕК"]
let standingExersiseImage = ["bb", "bt", "ca", "co", "de"]

let sittingExersiseName = ["ПРИСЕД", "СКАЧКИ", "ПРИСЕДАНИЯ", "ОТЖИМАНИЯ", "ТОЛЧЕК"]
let sittingExersiseImage = ["bb", "bt", "ca", "co", "de"]

var segmentControler: SMSegmentView!
var alphaSegmentView: SMBasicSegmentView!
var seletionBar: UIView = UIView()


override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
  //СОЗДАЕМ СЕГМЕНТ
  self.view.frame = CGRectMake(-5.0 , 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width + 10, 40.0)
 self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 241.0/255.0, green: 83.0/255.0, blue: 84.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
 let segmentFrame = CGRect(x: -5.0 , y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.size.width + 10, height: 40.0)

self.segmentControler = SMSegmentView(frame: segmentFrame, separatorColour: UIColor(red: 241.0/255.0, green: 83.0/255.0, blue: 84.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0), separatorWidth: 0.0, segmentProperties: [keySegmentTitleFont: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16.0), keySegmentOnSelectionColour: UIColor(red: 241.0/255.0, green: 83.0/255.0, blue: 84.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0), keySegmentOffSelectionColour: UIColor(red: 241.0/255.0, green: 83.0/255.0, blue: 84.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)])

self.segmentControler.delegate = self
self.segmentControler.addSegmentWithTitle("STANDING", onSelectionImage: nil, offSelectionImage: nil)
self.segmentControler.addSegmentWithTitle("SITTING", onSelectionImage: nil, offSelectionImage: nil)
self.segmentControler.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 241.0/255.0, green: 83.0/255.0, blue: 84.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor

self.seletionBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 33.5, width: self.segmentControler.frame.size.width/CGFloat(self.segmentControler.numberOfSegments), height: 6.0)
self.seletionBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

self.segmentControler.selectSegmentAtIndex(0)

self.view.addSubview(self.segmentControler)
}
func segmentView(segmentView: SMBasicSegmentView, didSelectSegmentAtIndex index: Int) {

 let placeSelectionBar = { () -> () in
    var barFrame = self.seletionBar.frame
    barFrame.origin.x = barFrame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
    self.seletionBar.frame = barFrame
}
if self.seletionBar.superview == nil {
    self.segmentControler.addSubview(self.seletionBar)
    placeSelectionBar()
}
else {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
        placeSelectionBar()
    })
}
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

var returnValue = 0

switch (segmentControler.indexOfSelectedSegment) {
case 0: // NOT WORK ON SIMULATOR 
    returnValue = standingExersiseName.count
    break
case 1: // NOT WORK ON SIMULATOR
    returnValue = sittingExersiseName.count
    break

default:
    break
}
 return returnValue
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

switch (segmentControler.indexOfSelectedSegment) {
case 0: // NOT WORK ON SIMULATOR
    myCell.textLabel?.text = standingExersiseName[indexPath.row]
    myCell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named:standingExersiseImage[indexPath.row])
    break
case 1: // NOT WORK ON SIMULATOR
    myCell.textLabel?.text = sittingExersiseName[indexPath.row]
    myCell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named:sittingExersiseImage[indexPath.row])
    break

default:
    break
}

return myCell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We must add to didSelectSegmentAtIndex "standingTableView.reloadData ()"